# How Can i fetch all product name in 1 table without creating new table or th

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to make a single table only for product name and quantity but every time i add new delivery it creates a table here's my screen shot i hope you guys help me

[Here is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX9ri.jpg)

[I want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5tbh.jpg)

[Here are my table and database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SiM5.png)

Here Code->>> 1 form [ORDER.PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rGpF.jpg)
Here Code->>> 2 form[ORDER.PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94NCv.jpg)

Here Code->>> 1 fetch[ORDER_FETCH.PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MLNW.jpg)
 
Here Code->>>  2 fetch [ORDER_FETCH.PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwxak.png)

please help me guys thank you.

Comment: Please show us your table schemas, sample data, and the query you're using to retrieve the data.

Comment: okay sir I'll provide here

Comment: is i posted it again please check it ty

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your code as plain text, not an image. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in your query to get all the materials for each order.

```
SELECT ..., GROUP_CONCAT(material, '#', quantity) AS materials
FROM ...
GROUP BY inventory_order_id
```

Then when you're processing the row, you can explode this and get the materials and corresponding properties into two arrays. Finally, you can join each of these arrays with `<br>` to get them on different lines in the table cells.

```
$materials = array();
$quantities = array();
foreach (explode(',', $row['materials'] as $material) {
    list ($name, $quantity) = explode('#'. $material);
    $materials[] = $name;
    $quantities[] = $quantity;
}
$material_html = implode('<br>', $materials;
$quantity_html = implode('<br>', $quantities;
```

Comment: I'll try it later sir

Comment: sir barmar can you help me

Comment: Sorry, can't spend much time here today.